# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError when loading data from Excel to Snowflake

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from excel to Snowflake using Python.

Below is my code so far:

```
config = ConfigParser()

# parse ini file
config.read('config.ini')

## Read excel
file = '/path/INTRANSIT.xlsx'

df_excel = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')

# sqlalchemy to create DB engine
engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = config.get('Production', 'accountname'),
    user = config.get('Production', 'username'),
    password = config.get('Production', 'password'),
    database = config.get('Production', 'dbname'),
    schema = config.get('Production', 'schemaname'),
    warehouse = config.get('Production', 'warehousename'),
    role=config.get('Production', 'rolename'),
)
)
con = engine.connect()

df_excel.to_sql('transit_table',con, if_exists='replace', index=False) 

con.close()
```

But I am getting below error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in Engine(snowflake://username:***@account_identifier/): (db.schema.transit_table)
```

I have tried prefixing Database and schema to table and also tried passing table name alone. I have also tried passing uppercase and lowercase table name.

Still not able to resolve this error. Would really appreciate any help to resolve this!

Thank you.

Comment: Did you checked the table name within database as what it shows - in case its quotes enclosed or anything? Also, is it just this one table in the DB or for any table you get same error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The table is not in double quotes. This issue is for all tables.

Comment: @etluser Are you sure you have a role with enough permissions to create a table in that schema? I am able to run your code just fine and I get the table created and the data imported.

Comment: @Sergiu - Thank you for your response. The issue was with the excel column names. It has spaces. Used df_excel.rename() and removed spaces to map it with DB table.